# XAMARIN - Failed to resolve "System.Reflection.Emit.AssemblyBuilder" reference from "mscorlib, Version=2.0.5.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=abc"

Tags: c#, mvvm, xamarin, xamarin.ios

I'm keep getting this irritating error when building my project on iOS platform. Is this has anything to do with the Xamarin updates?

How can I fix this? Thanks in advances

Comment: Which versions of Xamarin and Visual Studio are you running? Has your project been building previously - if so, what has changed? Have you tried creating a new, minimal project/solution, to see if that builds?

Comment: @Steve I've managed to fix this error. The main reason for this is because I use package Mono.Android inside my Core (PCL) project. Remove the package and this should do the trick. Thanks tho

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The main reason for this is because I use package Mono.Android inside my Core (PCL) project. Remove the package and this should do the trick.